# What is the main difference between a Compiler and a Transpiler?

Tags: compilation, transpiler

What are the main differences between a `Compiler` and a `Transpiler`? Please could you provide some examples of both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler Vs Interpreter Vs Transpiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246498/compiler-vs-interpreter-vs-transpiler)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They're essentially the same: take source code and transform it to something else.

The difference is that compiler usually produces a directly usable artifact (executable binary of some sort). Example: **C** (produces binary), **C#** (produces bytecode).

Whereas transpiler produces another form of source code (in another language, for example), which is not directly runnable and needs to be compiled/interpreted. Example: **CoffeeScript** transpiler, which produces javascript. **Opal** (converts ruby to javascript)

Answer (score 4):

**Compiler** - compiles code to a lower level code.

Example:

- `"Developer code"` -> `"Machine code"`
- `PHP` -> `C`
- `Java` -> `bytecode`

**Transpiler** - compiles code to same level of code/abstraction.

Example:

- `"Developer code"` -> `"Another developer code or version"`
- `JavaScript ES2015+` -> `JavaScript ES5`